# React className conditional logic blocks transition from happening, no idea why

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create an accordion with React. I asked a question on this previously on StackOverflow in terms of, how do I assign classes to an accordion on click and open multiple at once. Somebody linked me the below code sandbox which will toggle a background colour on click.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-http-n0omm?file=/src/App.js

So, I have tried to put it into my code to open and close the accordion, and it will not transition no matter what I do. It is an instant change and I can't seem to figure out why. I have also tried making the transition from a bg colour of blue, to red, and same thing, it instantly changes with no transition.

Can somebody look at my code and help figure it out?

The only difference I have noticed in the difference between the code sandbox and my code, is that on the sandbox version, on the dom using inspect element, when the button is clicked, only the selected element flashes purple (chrome) to indicate something is changed. On my version, EVERY instance of the map flashes purple, to indicate that all the elements mapped out have been affected in some way.

```
  const [accordionOpen, setAccordionOpen] = useState([]);


  function openAccordion(num) {
    setAccordionOpen((state) => {
      return state.includes(num)
        ? state.filter((n) => n !== num)
        : [...state, num];
    });
  }




return parsedData.map((data) => {
<>
<div
                className="mortgage_moreinfo"
                onClick={() => openAccordion(data.ProductCode)}
                key={data.ProductCode}
              >
                <p>More Info</p>
              </div>
</>
})
```

SCSS

```
.accordionClosed {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordionOpen {
  max-height: 101px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your scss:

```
.accordion {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordion.open {
  max-height: 101px !important;
}
```

And for your React Component:

```
 <div className=`accordion ${ConditionForOpeningTheAccordion ? 'open' : ''}`>
 </div>
```

So you are basically having a `.accordion` class wich defines the basic style for your accordion, but with your height of 0px. And when your condition for opening the accordion is met you are adding the `.open` class to the accordion wich has a width of 101px. This should ensure, that your transition gets played every time the `.open` class gets removed or added to the accordion.

I hope my explanation helps you. If not I can provide a codesandbox or something like that.